# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SQLiteOpenHelper, SQLite DB does not work on Android 4.X

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

my application works on Android 5.0+ fine, but I get an error on Android 4.4 (Galaxy S4 Mini).

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.lernapp.datenbank.FragenTabelle
at de.lernapp.datenbank.LernAppDB.onCreate(LernAppDB.java:41)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
at de.lernapp.lernApp.ErsteAnmeldungActivity.onCreate(ErsteAnmeldungActivity.java:81)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Has anyone a solution for this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and paste code.

Comment: Agree. The question's title does not stick to the exception

Comment: What's `de.myapplication.database.Table`? Is it an extension from some other class? I'm guessing `Table`'s parent class is only available on 5.0 and up.

Comment: It's a normal java claas, where I generate a Table for the Database. In my Code the class name is "FrageTabelle". But i renamed it here.

Comment: No solution for my problem?